# typedef не в начале объявления

Tags: c++, c, typedef

Увидел следующий код:

```
int typedef *Ptr;
```

Что он означает? Неужели можно ставить `typedef` не в начале объявления?

Comment: Ого, [компилируется](https://tio.run/##Sy4o0E1PTv7/PzOvRKGksiA1JTVNQSugpMiaiwsklJuYmaehqVCtUJRaUlqUp2BgrVD7/z8A). Никогда не видел.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typedef: "Typically, the typedef specifier appears at the start of the declaration, though it is permitted to appear after the type specifiers, or between two type specifiers."

Comment: А вас никогда не смущала запись, где в конце объявления структуры, пишется `} typedef name:`?

Comment: Никогда так не писал. Всегда `typedef struct S {...} S;`.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать typedef и после объявления, например :

```
struct expl{
    int a;
}typedef expl1;
```

Теперь ваша struct expl называется просто expl1(имя может быть любое другое).И когда вы будете создавать экземпляр данной структуры, тип данных вы сможете писать просто "expl1"

Приведу другой пример:

```
      int typedef a; // мы "переименновали" int в a
      a b = 8;// b на самом деле имеет тип данных int
```

Что касается именно вашего примера, я с ним разобраться не смог, приведите пожалуйста полный код.